# Diff software for Mac

Tags: macos, diff

not sure if this is the right place to ask this. I have been looking for a good "Diff"ing software for Mac OSx 10.8.3, something like "Meld", which has a clear GUI and it is possible to edit the files directly in the GUI. I failed to install Meld on Mac. And I couldn't find any good alternatives. Opendiff works not badly, but it is a bit slow to edit the files directly.

Any sugggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FileMerge application found at "/Developer/Applications/Utilities/FileMerge.app".

Comment: I find it has the same issue. I cannot edit the files inside the GUI.

Comment: Try re-installing it using following DMG https://www.macupdate.com/download/25426/DiffMerge.3.3.2.1139.dmg

Comment: In my recently updated Xcode, the executable is at `Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge` within `/Applications/Xcode.app/`. Any idea how to run it from a command line?

Comment: @drevicko You can use that path to run from the command line on OS X: $ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge